# Why doesn't the Python interpreter return the explicit SyntaxError message?

Tags: python, cpython, python-internals

When looking at CPython's [`tokenizer.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Parser/tokenizer.c), the tokenizer returns specific error messages.

As an example, you can take a look at the part where the tokenizer tries to [parse a decimal number](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e676244235895aeb6ec3b81ca3ccf4a70e487919/Parser/tokenizer.c#L1084). When trying to parse the number `5_6` everything should be OK, but when trying to parse the number `5__6` the tokenizer should return a SyntaxError with the message "invalid decimal literal":

```
static int
tok_decimal_tail(struct tok_state *tok)
{
    int c;

    while (1) {
        do {
            c = tok_nextc(tok);
        } while (isdigit(c));
        if (c != '_') {
            break;
        }
        c = tok_nextc(tok);
        if (!isdigit(c)) {
            tok_backup(tok, c);
            syntaxerror(tok, "invalid decimal literal");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Using Python, I've tried to reach the tokenizer's `SyntaxError` message:

```
In [12]: try: 
    ...:     eval('5__6') 
    ...: except SyntaxError as e: 
    ...:     print(e.args, e.filename, e.lineno, e.msg, e.text) 

('invalid token', ('<string>', 1, 2, '5__6')) <string> 1 invalid token 5__6
```

Is there any way to extract the SyntaxError message from the tokenizer?

Comment: It returns `0`, not a `SyntaxError`. The message is passed to `syntaxerror`.

Comment: @Goyo; yeah, that's right. It does return `syntaxerror` in other places though. Look at [Line 1453](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Parser/tokenizer.c#L1453) and try to compile the line "0xk" in your interpreter. It returns `syntaxerror` with the right error message, but you can't extract it in the interpreter.

Comment: @Goyo: the tokenizer sets an exception on the tokenizer state, and that results in a syntax error exception being raised.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking at source code that is only present in Python 3.8a1 and newer, see the [pull request that introduced this message in July 2018](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/6517):

> bpo-33305: Improve SyntaxError for invalid numerical literals. (GH-6517)

and the attached [Python issue #33305](https://bugs.python.org/issue33305).

When I run your code with Python 3.8b2 (the current beta) I see the message you expected:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=0, releaselevel='beta', serial=2)    
>>> try:
...     eval('5__6')
... except SyntaxError as e:
...     print(e.args, e.filename, e.lineno, e.msg, e.text)
...
('invalid decimal literal',) <string> 1 invalid decimal literal None
```

You tried this out on Python 3.7 or older, so won't yet see the newer messages.